# Invalid value for prop `reset` on <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I was getting this warning:

> react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Invalid value for prop `reset` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM. For details, see https://reactjs.org/link/attribute-behavior

This came from my custom hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export const useField = (type) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const reset = () => {
    setValue('')
  }

  return {
    type,
    value,
    onChange,
    reset
  }
}
```

The hook is used in a component:

```
const CreateNew = (props) => {
  const content = useField('text')
  const author = useField('text')
  const info = useField('text')

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    props.addNew({
      content: content.value,
      author: author.value,
      info: info.value,
      votes: 0
    })
    navigate('/')
    props.setNotification(`a new anecdote ${content.value} created!`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      props.setNotification(null)
    }, 5000)
  }

  const handleReset = (event) => {
    console.log(content)
    content.onReset()
    author.onReset()
    info.onReset()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>create a new anecdote</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          content
          <input {...content} />
        </div>
        <div>
          author
          <input {...author} />
        </div>
        <div>
          url for more info
          <input {...info} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">create</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleReset}>reset</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The warning disappeared when I change the name of the function `reset` to `onReset`, but I don't understand why.

Is `onReset` a special keyword for react or something? I changed it on pure luck and the problem was gone but I don't get why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

You are passing a `reset` prop/attribute to an `input` element that is an invalid attribute value, it's a function, not a string or a number.

```
const useField = (type) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
  const reset = () => {
    setValue("");
  };

  return {
    type,
    value, // <-- is a function
    onChange,
    reset
  };
};
```

...

```
const content = useField('text'); // <-- includes reset function
```

...

```
<input {...content} /> // <-- reset spread to input, causes error
```

See [input tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) for a list of valid attributes.

The reason React doesn't flag the name `onReset` is because this ***is*** a valid event handler (*but for `form` elements, not `input`*), see [Synthetic Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

---

#### Your Question

> Is onReset a special keyword for react or something? I changed it on
> pure luck and the problem was gone but I don't get why.

If you follow the link in the warning, buried in the page is this note.

> *Note: attributes starting with on are not passed through as an
> exception because this could become a potential security hole.*

---

Additionally there's an issue in the `handleReset` callback that is referencing undefined properties and attempting to invoke them, which will obviously throw an error when the preceding issues are resolved.

```
const handleReset = (event) => {
  console.log(content);
  content.onReset(); // <-- onReset is undefined, should call content.reset()
  author.onReset();
  info.onReset();
};
```

## Solution

Destructure the `reset` function from the `useField` hook's return value and spread the rest into a props object. Reference the correct reset function in `handleReset`.

Example:

```
const CreateNew = (props) => {
  const { reset: resetContent, ...content } = useField("text");
  const { reset: resetAuthor, ...author } = useField("text");
  const { reset: resetInfo, ...info } = useField("text");

  ...

  const handleReset = (event) => {
    console.log(content);
    resetContent();
    resetAuthor();
    resetInfo();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>create a new anecdote</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          content
          <input {...content} />
        </div>
        <div>
          author
          <input {...author} />
        </div>
        <div>
          url for more info
          <input {...info} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">create</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleReset}>
          reset
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit invalid-value-for-prop-reset-on-input-tag]

Comment: Thanks man, this was a very good solution but I didnt get why the problem is solved when I use the name "onReset". Like I ask at the end of my post, I want to know why "·The warning disappeared when I change the name of the function "reset" to "onReset" but i dont understand why. Is onReset a special keyword for react or something? " Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Juan41 Sorry, I thought it was clear. `reset` isn't a valid `input` tag attribute. The link in the error message explains the React behavior why it's just a warning and that if you *really* want `reset` to be passed through to the DOM that it should be a number or a string value, not a function. `onReset` ***is*** an event handler prop in React that can be attached to certain html elements, i.e. `form`. I've updated my answer a bit. Hope that clears it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

"reset" is a [reserved prop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset) for an input field to reset a form. You can't use reset as a function in your prop spread. try "clearValue" as a function name instead

```js
export const useField = (type) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    const onChange = (event) => {
      setValue(event.target.value)
    }
    const reset = () => {
        setValue('')
    }

    return {
      type,
      value,
      onChange,
      clearValue: reset
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried a lot of names and only onReset was the one that didnt make the error. I cant understand why tho

Comment: I think you are thinking of `type="reset"` on the input tag to reset a form. `reset` itself isn't an attribute on the `input` tag.